# possible to use <img> as <div>?

Tags: html, css

for example if I want to put an image wrap another object,possible?

```
<img src='pic.png'>
<div id='block'>
<p>Somebody
</div>
</img>
```

I know I should just use `div` and background-image but I want to use the property `auto`

```
img{width:50%; height:auto;}
```

If I use `div` , using auto won't works because it won't know the background-image size and will not adjust the div depends on the image ratio aspect.

Comment: can you describe a little more specifically what you are trying to achieve here so that we can give you the best solution?

Comment: **NO.**  An `<img>` is not a container.  Just set your image to be whatever size you want, and position it so its `z-index` makes it behind your content.

Comment: I want the img to be scale proportionally depends on user screen width,also with the 'block' inside, if I use another div to wrap all of them, they will just depend on the width of the div, and won't scale in proportion of the image.

Comment: <img> does not have a closing tag , can't be done like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`img` it's an inline tag, so it shouldn't have descendant elements.

> The IMG element embeds an image in the current document at the location of the element's definition. **The IMG element has no content**; it is usually replaced inline by the image designated by the src attribute, the exception being for left or right-aligned images that are "floated" out of line.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.2)

Comment: More exactly, an `img` element *cannot* have descendant elements, both due to HTML specifications and to the way browsers actually parse documents.